using gnu date to set a time and format and subtract
Can I give GNU date a date and format string for that date and tell it to also subtract some time from it? It seems I can do 2 of 3 in 1 command but not all
I have this date format:
09/Sep/24 05:02 AM and I need to subtract 1 day from it:
For example:
09/Sep/24 05:02 AM - 1 day ago should yield 08/Sep/24 05:02 AM
I have tried
So, this does the math:
date "+%m/%d/%y %H:%M %r" -d "1 hour ago"
and produces
09/09/24 14:52 02:52:30 PM (good, except I didn't tell it to produce seconds)
This doesn't work at all
date "+%m/%b/%y %H:%M %r" -d "09/Sep/24 05:02 AM"
date: invalid date ‘09/Sep/24 05:02 AM’

even though this does:
date "+%m/%b/%y %H:%M %r" 
09/Sep/24 15:55 03:55:49 PM

Again, including seconds I don't want.
According to this post, the following should work:
date -d "09/Sep/24 05:02 AM - 2 hours" '+%m/%b/%y %H:%M %r'
date: invalid date ‘09/Sep/24 05:02 AM - 2 hours’

Is it possible to do this with gnu date in 1 line?

Edit the question and clarify the expected output. Is it in the format of 09/Sep/24 15:55 03:55 PM or 09/09/24 15:55 03:55 PM?

AFAIK 09/Sep/24 isn't one of GNU date's recognized calendar date input formats - in particular, / doesn't seem to be a supported separator for literal months, only for numeric months. See Date input formats - Calendar date items

@steeldriver That is true but it is still possible to get what is needed in the format the desired format. There are caveats but nothing to worry about for what is requested.

info date 'date input formats' will tell you which date formats GNU date accepts as input (same online for the latest version of GNU coreutils).
And 09/Sep/24 05:02 AM is not one of the ones it recognises. Any date format that doesn't specify the UTC offset is also ambiguous as you don't know which timezone it refers to, and even if we assume local time, there are times in the year when we can't know whether it's winter or summer time (for those timezones where DST applies).
For the output format, see here.

%r
locale's 12-hour clock time (e.g., ‘11:11:04 PM’)

So, that's locale-dependent. See the output of locale t_fmt_ampm to see what it is in your locale. In mine:
$ locale t_fmt_ampm
%l:%M:%S %P %Z
$ date +%r
 4:52:55 am BST
$ date +'%l:%M:%S %P %Z'
 4:53:01 am BST

It does include seconds.
An unambiguous format, simple to parse and recognised by many things including GNU, BSD, busybox, toybox, ast-open's date, zsh's and all languages' strftime builtin/function, ksh93/bash's printf %T is the epoch time (the number of Unix seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000) in decimal, though depending on the tool, it needs to be prefixed with # or @ when specified as input.
$ GNU-date -d @1725941251
Tue 10 Sep 05:07:31 BST 2024
$ BSD-date -r 1725941251
Tue Sep 10 05:07:31 BST 2024
$ busybox date -d @1725941251
Tue Sep 10 05:07:31 BST 2024
$ ast-date -d '#1725941251'
Tue Sep 10 05:07:31 BST 2024
$ toybox date -d @1725941251
Tue Sep 10 05:07:31 BST 2024
$ ksh -c 'printf "%T\n" "#1725941251"'
Tue Sep 10 05:07:31 BST 2024
$ bash -c 'printf "%(%c)T\n" 1725941251'
Tue 10 Sep 2024 05:07:31 BST
$ zsh -c 'zmodload zsh/datetime; strftime %c 1725941251'
Tue 10 Sep 2024 05:07:31 BST
$ gawk 'BEGIN{print strftime("%c", 1725941251)}'
Tue 10 Sep 2024 05:07:31 BST

One format that is human readable and supported as input format by many things including most of the date implementations that accept date as input for anything other than setting the clock accept those is the ISO 8601 variant in the form YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ZZ {+,-}ZZZZ as produced by date '+%F %T %z'.
$ date '+%F %T %z'
2024-09-10 05:07:31 +0100

$ GNU-date -d '2024-09-10 05:07:31 +0100'
Tue 10 Sep 05:07:31 BST 2024
$ busybox date -d '2024-09-10 05:07:31 +0100'
Tue Sep 10 05:07:31 BST 2024
$ ast-date -d '2024-09-10 05:07:31 +0100'
Tue Sep 10 05:07:31 BST 2024
$ ksh -c 'printf "%T\n" "2024-09-10 05:07:31 +0100"'
Tue Sep 10 05:07:31 BST 2024

(for busybox, ENABLE_FEATURE_TIMEZONE must be enabled at build time)
To be able to use an arbitrary date format as input, you need a tool or date implementation that supports specifying the input format (the standard +fmt is for the output format, and btw should come after the options as it's a non-option argument). That includes ast-open date with the -p option busybox date (if compiled in) with -D, BSD date with -jf, zsh's strftime -r, ksh93's printf %T (also ast-open's date) with the $DATEMSK environment variable but not GNU date (yet, see past discussion where the feature was considered or this bug request).
Also beware that strings like Sep are locale dependent. So to parse English ones, you'll want to set the locale to one where English is the language (could be the C locale in this case).
$ LC_ALL=C GNU-date -p '%d/%b/%y %I:%M %p' -d '09/Sep/24 05:02 AM'
Mon Sep  9 05:02:00 BST 2024
$ LC_ALL=C BSD-date -r0 -jf '%d/%b/%y %I:%M %p' '09/Sep/24 05:02 AM'
Mon Sep  9 05:02:00 BST 2024
$ LC_ALL=C busybox date -D '%d/%b/%y %I:%M %p' -d '09/Sep/24 05:02 AM'
Mon Sep  9 05:02:00 BST 2024
$ LC_ALL=C zsh -c 'zmodload zsh/datetime; strftime -rs t "%d/%b/%Y %I:%M %p" "09/Sep/2024 05:02 AM" && strftime %c $t'
Mon Sep  9 05:02:00 2024
$ LC_ALL=C ksh -c 'DATEMSK=/dev/stdin <<<"%d/%b/%Y %I:%M %p" printf "%T\n" "09/Sep/2024 05:02 AM"'
Mon Sep  9 05:02:00 BST 2024

(those assumed the date referred to my local time).
Beware the format specifiers there are those of strptime() which only cover a subset of those of strftime().
Now, when it comes to do calculation on those, it becomes even less portable. GNU and ast-open's date / ksh93's printf support some syntax for relative timespecs but the syntax varies between them. BSD dates have a more formal and unambiguous way to do it with their -v option.
The easiest is often to work with epoch time where you get an integer number of seconds. You'd do:

convert your human readable date+time spec into an epoch time as a decimal number.
do calculation on that by adding subtracting seconds
convert the result back into the human readable format of your choice.

zsh's strftime builtin is good for that
$ zmodload zsh/datetime
$ export LC_ALL=C
$ format='%d/%b/%Y %I:%M %p'
$ datetime='09/Sep/2024 05:02 AM'
$ strftime -rs t $format $datetime
$ (( t -= 2 * 60 * 60 ))
$ strftime $format $t
09/Sep/2024 03:02 AM

If you have to use GNU date, since that implementation doesn't support specifying the input format, you need to convert the $datetime into a format that it does recognises. That could be 09 Sep 2024 05:02 AM for instance (works with GNU or ast-open date, not other date implementations) for which we just need to replace the /s with spaces.
Here using a shell with support for ksh93's ${param//pattern/replacement} operator such as ksh93, zsh, bash, mksh, yash:
export LC_ALL=C
output_format='%d/%b/%Y %I:%M %p'
datetime='09/Sep/2024 05:02 AM'
t=$(date -d "${datetime//\// }" +%s)
(( t -= 2 * 60 * 60 ))
date -d "@$t" "+$output_format"

Or using GNU date's builtin support to compute offsets to dates:
export LC_ALL=C
output_format='%d/%b/%Y %I:%M %p'
datetime='09/Sep/2024 05:02 AM'
date -d "${datetime//\// } - 2 hours"


To get it in the format of printing the shortened name of the month of year without seconds:
date "+%d/%b/%y %H:%M %I:%M %p" -d "1 hour ago"

Output:
09/Sep/24 19:11 07:11 PM

To get the number of the month:
 date "+%d/%m/%y %H:%M %I:%M %p" -d "1 hour ago"

Output:
09/09/24 19:11 07:11 PM

The format of %I:%M %p prints the 12-hour time without seconds whereas %r prints the time with seconds.
Also, notice that the calendar dates in my commands are printed with +%d/%b/%y and +%d/%m/%y which print the number of the day, number of the month, and two-digit year and the number of the day, shortened month of the year, and two-digit year, respectively. You have it as +%m/%d/%y for one of your examples and +%m/%b/%y for another. What those are actually printing are the number of the month, the number of the day of the month, and the two-digit year and next, the number of the month, the shortened name of the month, and the two-digit year, respectively. It looks like it is printing the day, month, and year because the day of the month and the number of the month (September) are the same number today.
To better illustrate this, if you use your command
date "+%m/%d/%y %H:%M %r" -d "1 month ago"

You'll see that the output is
08/09/24 20:20 08:20:35 PM 

Which indicates the month is actually the first number whereas you want it to be the second number.
Keep in mind that the times are a bit off because they are from the times that I ran the commands. Also, if what is wanted is one day ago, simply change 1 hour ago to 1 day ago or whatever time in the past that you may want. It looks like you can manage that so I simply used your example as a template.

this doesn't seem to say anything about using an input like 09/Sep/24 05:02 AM?

well, the Q above seems to say "I have this date format: 09/Sep/24 05:02 AM and I need to subtract 1 day from it", and I don't see anything here about getting date to accept the date in that format as input

@ilkkachu The question says that and several other things. The first sentence says Can I give GNU date a date and format string for that date and tell it to also subtract some time from it? and it then gives an example of subtracting one hour. The concern appears to be not including the seconds as indicated twice. If one day ago is what is wanted, then it looks like the person can work that out and just change what is in my answer from 1 hour ago to 1 day ago and it will give the date as one day ago in the desired format. I simply used their example as a template.

@ilkkachu It gives the desired result in the requested format, does it not? I will agree that the other answer is more thorough and that is why it has been accepted whereas mine hasn't been but there's no need to split hairs for something like this considering that the utility doesn't recognize the desired format string anyway. If you disagree because you don't see it that way, then that's fine and I have no problem with that. The purpose of my answer is only to address the issue of removing the seconds which from what I can surmise, is the only area where the person was having difficulty.
